# How to add emails (but not users) to Google Apps shared Directory, preferrably by import

Tags: google, google-workspace, google-contacts, google-apps-email

I have a Google Apps (free) account. I wish to add email and other contact information to the (shared) directory.

1. How do I do this one at a time? Right now the directory just has the users' emails.
2. Is there a way to import vCards or other format for the directory? I see how to add them to the address book, but not the directory.

I don't have an existing Exchange or other setup to pull them from.

Update Dec 12 '11: Yes, under Settings>Contacts>Contact Sharing it is set for Enable contact sharing and Show all email addresses.

Comment: I do not understand when you say you want to add emails but not users. Are you saying you want to add emails to the shared contact list?

Comment: Yes, emails of outside people to the shared contact list.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Assuming that you want to add contacts (not users), follow these steps:

1. Make sure you have the Contacts service added to the domain. (https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/==yourdomain==/SelectServices)
2. Goto Contacts service settings and Enable contact sharing.
3. Now, goto: http://www.google.com/contacts/a/==yourdomain==
4. You can import contacts based on CSV or even vCard.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For step 1, I don't see that choice. I saw that on another screen, however. But this seems to add them to my contacts only, not to all users. Is there a step after this for sharing it to others?

Comment: When you have enabled contact sharing, everyone in your userbase must be able view these contacts.

Comment: I have added them as Shared Contacts using SherpaTools. But they aren't visible to the users. Or they and I don't know where to look.